# Как скачать excel файл с помощью fetch из React/Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs, excel, download

Подскажите пожалуйста, как скачать excel-файла, который  берется по api ссылке. само api написано на laravel, а библиотека для создания excel файла maatwebsite/excel.
Если ссылку вставлять сразу в браузер, то файл скачивается, как надо и с правильным содержимым.
"Погуглив", много где предлагают решение такого вида(используя blob):

```
 fetch("http://localhost:7777/api/v1/organizations/export", {
            responseType: "blob",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/vnd.ms-excel" }
        }).then(response => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
            const link = document.createElement("a");
            link.href = url;
            link.setAttribute("download", "template.xls");
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
        });
```

Но если это делаю через fetch, то файл пустой(не знаю почему). Смотрел в консоле: response.data - undefined. А сам response выглядит так:

```
Response
   body: ReadableStream { locked: false }
   bodyUsed: false
   headers: Headers {  }
   ok: true
   redirected: false
   status: 200
   statusText: "OK"
   type: "basic"
   url: "http://localhost:7777/api/v1/organizations/export"
```

Контроллер на laravel выглядит так:

```
class OrganizationsExportController extends Controller
{
    public function export()
    {
        return (new OrganizationsExport)->download('organizations_export.xls');
    }
}
```

А таблица "рисуется" тут с нужными параметрами:

```
class OrganizationsExport implements FromCollection, ShouldAutoSize, WithEvents, WithMapping, WithHeadings
{
    use Exportable;
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public function collection()
    {
        return ScheduledInspectionModel::all();
    }

    private $count = 0;

    public function map($organizations): array
    {
        return [
            ++$this->count,
            $organizations->name_smp,
            $organizations->name_control,
            $organizations->verification_start . ' - ' . $organizations->verification_end,
            $organizations->verification_duration,
        ];
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            '№',
            'Проверяемый СМП',
            'Контролирующий орган',
            'Период плановой проверки',
            'Плановая длительность',
        ];
    }

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event) {
                $event->sheet->getStyle('A1:F1')->applyFromArray([
                    'font' => [
                        'bold' => true
                    ]
                ]);
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще раз погуглив, понял что крутится все вокруг этого new Blob(). И сделал вот так:

```
const exportDataToFile = async () => {
    try {
        await fetch("http://localhost:7777/api/v1/organizations/export")
            .then(response => {
                if ((response.ok === true) & (response.status === 200)) {
                    return response.blob();
                }
            })
            .then(data => {
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
                const link = document.createElement("a");
                link.href = url;
                link.setAttribute("download", "organizations_export.xls");
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

ps: exportDataToFile ф-я которая просто вешается на клик кнопки.

Так же, а может и проще было воспользоваться библиотекой `file-saver`, но мне было интересно знать почему у меня самого не получалось.